# foreach variable equal to another variable

Tags: php, json, foreach

I want to foreach $key equal to $values to return the $called that matches the $key.

```
foreach($value as $values);
foreach($json['values'] as $key => $called) {
    if($key == $values) {
        $myreturns[] = $called;
    }
}
return json_encode($myreturns, true);
```

I have a select multiple which value is a number and if not a number on registration it fails (to stop people changing values).

I populate it with the following json

```
{
"values": {
    "1": "Black",
    "2": "Blue",
    "3": "Brown",
    "4": "Grey",
    "5": "Green",
    "6": "Hazel",
    "7": "Violet"
}
```

}

if somebody chose black and blue, the values will be 1 and 2.

For example I want foreach $key so the json above if that number is equal to "1" to return the $called that is related to the $key.

I know this is wrong but I want something like this

```
foreach($key == $values) {
    $myreturns[] = $called;
}
```

Comment: This seems like the sort of thing `array_filter` is made for. I'm not certain, as I'm not clear on what exactly you're looking to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

Close.  use array_push to push the results into a new array, then json encode that.

```
// json decode into associative array
$values = json_decode($json, true);

// init results
$results = array();

foreach($values as $key => $value) {
    if($called == $key) {
        array_push($results,$value);
    }
}
$result = json_encode($result);
return $result;
```

Also note that if you want to get an item within a json array, it is easier to just reference it within the array:

```
$array = json_decode($json,true);
$item = $array[$key];
```